# Duplicate published method Error message when running UI in debugging mode

Tags: delphi, tms, tms-web-core

When attempting to run UI with debugging then it gives this error...

> Duplicate published method "WebMemo1Change" at...

[image: Error Message]

What may be the cause of it and how would you correct the error?

Was attempting to align text in memo to center, however when I added code it didn't work so removed the added code and attempted to run Delphi in debugging mode however recieved this message

Comment: Please, never post images of error messages or code. The text in the image speaks about `PasToJs`. Is that something related to `tms`, or what?

Comment: @TomBrunberg `PasToJs` is the transpiler that `TMS WEB Core` uses to transpile the code from `Pascal` to `JavaScript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two or more `onChange` events declared for your `WebMemo1`.

If you look through your `.pas` file, you'll see somewhere in there you'll have multiple `WebMemo1Change` method declarations. It'll look something like this:

```
procedure WebMemo1Change(Sender: TObject);
procedure WebMemo1Change(Sender: TObject);
```

Just remove the duplicate ones. There can only be one that is declared with that name.